# Finding limit of fraction with square roots: $\lim_{r\to 9} \frac {\sqrt{r}} {(r-9)^4}$

Tags: calculus

I have been looking at this for five minutes, no clue what to do.

$$\lim_{r\to 9} \frac {\sqrt{r}} {(r-9)^4}$$

Comment: (You mean $r$, not $t$, right?) Are you sure that's the problem? It's of the form $3/0$ as written.

Comment: do you mean "$r$ approaches 9"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $r$ is close to 9, then the numerator $\sqrt r$ is close to 3 and the denominator, $(r-9)^4$, is positive and close to 0. So, if you take a number close to 3 and divide by a small positive number, what do you get?

If you take  numbers appoaching 3 and divide by   small positive numbers approaching 0, what do you get?

---

Look at some specific values:
$$
\matrix{r& \quad\sqrt r\qquad&\qquad (r-9)^4\qquad & {\sqrt r\over (1-9)^4} \cr

9.1&\approx3 &.1^4 &\approx{3\over .1^4}=3\cdot 10,000  \cr

9.01&\approx3 &.01^4 &\approx{3\over .01^4}=3\cdot 10^8  \cr

9.001&\approx3 &.001^4 &\approx{3\over .001^4}=3\cdot 10^{12}  \cr


8.9&\approx3 &(-.1)^4 &\approx{3\over .1^4}=3\cdot 10,000  \cr

8.99&\approx3 &(-.01)^4 &\approx{3\over .01^4}=3\cdot 10^8  \cr

8.999&\approx3 &(-.001)^4 &\approx{3\over .001^4}=3\cdot 10^{12}  \cr



}
$$

Note the closer $r$ is to 9, the bigger $\sqrt r\over (r-9)^4$ becomes. So the limit is infinite.

Note also, please, that because the denominator is being raised to an *even* power, it is always positive.

The limit $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow9} {\sqrt r\over (r-9)^3}$  is quite different, and in fact does not exist.

Comment: That line of thinking doesn't really make any sense to me at all. It isn't how things really work. For example doing that on this problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106164/finding-a-limit-with-a-cube/106168#106168 causes a lot of problems. You would assume the answer is 2/0 which it is not.

Comment: @Jordan: You're misreading the situation. We have $(-1)^3+1=0$, not $=2$ like you think.

Comment: @Jordan, it doesn't work there, because you wind up with $0/0$ in that case (or "something small divided by something small", which does not lead you anywhere). Here everything is  fine: the numerator is "more or less 3" and the denominator is small and positive (the "positive" is important). 3 divided by something small gets you something big...

Answer (score 2):

The limit is $+\infty$ because the numerator approaches a positive number and the denominator approaches $0$ from above.  Sometimes one says the limit "doesn't exist" when one means there is no real number that is the limit, so you could put it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing $r$ by $r-9$,
this becomes
$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac {\sqrt{r+9}} {r^4}
$. 
As was said, the numerator goes to 3
and the denominator goes to 0,
so the quotient goes to $\infty$.